# Solve differential equation and showed output using Handcalcs

Tags: python, equation, differential-equations

`

```
import sympy as sp

# Define the symbolic variables
x = sp.symbols('x')
y = sp.Function('y')(x)

# Define the ODE
ode = sp.Eq(y.diff(x), x)

# Solve the ODE
solution = sp.dsolve(ode, y)

# Display the solution
print(solution)
```

`

this above code gives the solution format as - Eq(y(x), C1 + x**2/2).
But i want the answer will be in the book format. And i want to do it by using 'Handcalcs'(https://github.com/connorferster/handcalcs#basic-demo). How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.